# How to convert files with extensions wmf, bmp, dwg, dxf to use in OpenLayer?

Tags: angular, openlayers, autocad

currently, I am working on POC and trying to build some kind of map engine. I have implemented already and incorporated OpenLayer with Angular 6 and Material Design. It looks nice, but I got a new requirement that user should be able to import files in the formats like wmf, bmp, dwg, dxf, originally from AutoCad.

---

**Use case**: User/Client drew floor and want to add it to map engine than add some custom features like camera, polygon etc.

it's not a problem to do it with the static image, but I am looking for a way to implement based on specified file formats.

---

### Current observation:

- OpenLayers doesn't support those formats;
- I can try to convert dwg, dxf in vector format like GeoJson, but with loss of original quality of the drawing (dwg, dxf - do not fully support open vector format - KML, GeoJson) - for me its a crutch;
- simply convert it to image png/jpg and load as static source - the easiest way  to do so, but I am not satisfied with quality when zoom image;
- implement own ol.source to work with one of this format;

Answer (score 0):

Create a rest service and transform the files to the shapefile using python converters.Host the shapefile as a wfs service and serve to the client and finally if the client wants to download the data and use the wfs as the source and push a geojson back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at libraries that can convert those format in json you can parse to create your layers.

[gdsestimating/dxf-parser](https://github.com/gdsestimating/dxf-parser) could do it for dxf.

Comment: Thank you, but I found the better way for me. Convert dxf to svg and upload it as a static image in OL.